# How to remove only certain elements inside <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href, jquery-wrap

How do I remove only certain elements inside an `<a>` tag, not all of it (like `unwrap()` does)? For instance I have:

```
<a href="#page1" class="link" id="page1link" onclick="return false">1</a>
<a href="#page2" class="link" id="page2link" onclick="return false">2</a>
```

When I'm on page 1 (I fade out/in pages when clicking the link, so if I'm on page1 then page2 is invisible) I'd like the `1` to be only text, and same thing if I'm on page 2, no link attached to it, so I used:

```
if ($('#page1').is(':visible')) {
    $('#page1link').contents().unwrap();
    $('#page2link').wrap('<a href="#page2" onclick="return false" class="link" id="page2link"></a>');
} else {
    $('#page2link').contents().unwrap();
    $('#page1link').wrap('<a href="#page1" onclick="return false" class="link" id="page1link"></a>');
}
```

This unwraps it and turns `1` into plain text, but does not succeed in re-wrapping it with a link as once it turns into plain text, it loses its ID of "page1link" and can't be identified to get re-wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the anchor with a span:

```
if ($('#page1').is(':visible')) {
    $('#page1link').contents().unwrap().wrap('<span id="page1link">');
    $('#page2link').contents().unwrap().wrap('<a href="#page2" onclick="return false" class="link" id="page2link"></a>');
} else {
    $('#page2link').contents().unwrap().wrap('<span id="page2link">');
    $('#page1link').contents().unwrap().wrap('<a href="#page1" onclick="return false" class="link" id="page1link"></a>');
}
```